# Tips to Speed up the keras sequence generator?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, multiprocess

I have a custom data generator that inherence `tf.keras.utils.Sequence` class. And I have found that in tensorflow doc, `tf.data` is more efficient to use and recommend. But re-writing `Sequence` to `tf.data` can be costly. There are two option I can do

- one: optimize Sequence generator and integrate some advanced mechanism to boost it speed
- two: rewrite to `tf.data` from previous data loader

For now, I want to choose one. How can we speed up `sequence` data loader speed in training time?  Not the conventional way but some more smart approach. Thanks.